# C++/WinRT KeyDown event handler not being added in release mode

Tags: visual-c++, winrt-xaml, c++-winrt, windows-terminal

I'm trying to make some changes to the open source [Microsoft Terminal application](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/v1.3.2382.0/src/cascadia/TerminalApp/Tab.cpp#L705).

I'm adding a `KeyDown` event listener to an existing textbox.

Everything works as expected when I run the app with a Debug configuration, but when I run the same code under `Release` the `KeyDown` event handler is not added to the control.

I'm running: Release, x64, CascadiaPackage.

---

Here's the original code adding the `KeyUp` handler:

```
    // Tab.cpp (original)
    Controls::TextBox tabTextBox;
    
    // ...

    tabTextBox.KeyUp([weakThis](const IInspectable& sender, Input::KeyRoutedEventArgs const& e) {
        auto tab{ weakThis.get() };
        auto textBox{ sender.try_as<Controls::TextBox>() };
        if (tab && textBox)
        {
            // handle keyup event
        }
    });
```

Here's how I've added the `KeyDown` handler to the same control:

```
    // Tab.cpp (edited)
    auto sawKeyDown = false;
    
    /*
    !!! This event handler works in Debug but doesn't exist when run in Release configuration !!!
    */
    tabTextBox.KeyDown([&sawKeyDown](const IInspectable&, Input::KeyRoutedEventArgs const&) {
        sawKeyDown = true;
    });
    // !!!
    
    tabTextBox.KeyUp([weakThis, &sawKeyDown](const IInspectable& sender, Input::KeyRoutedEventArgs const& e) {
        auto tab{ weakThis.get() };
        auto textBox{ sender.try_as<Controls::TextBox>() };
        if (tab && textBox && sawKeyDown)
        {
            // ... original code here...
        }

        sawKeyDown = false;
    });
```

---

If I try to add a breakpoint inside the event handler in Release mode, Visual Studio shows this message on the breakpoint icon:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code of the debugger's target code type is associated with this line.
> Possible causes include: conditional compilation, compiler optimizations, or the target architecture of this line is not supported by the current debugger code type.
>
> Location: Tab.cpp, line 716 ('_ConstructTabRenameBox(const winrt::hstring& tabText)')

---

Is the code KeyDown listener being optimized out for some reason? Or is there something else I need to do to add the event listener to the textbox.

I've tried referencing `weakThis` inside the KeyDown handler but changing the code doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: May I know how did you judge the KeyDown event handler is not added to the control? You added a breakpoint inside the event handler in Release mode, the breakpoint was not triggered or other else? Since when I tried to change the text of textbox in KeyDown event, it could work well in both debug and release mode.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, registering for key events in a `TextBox` is likely choosing the wrong level of abstraction. A `TextBox` operates on *characters*, and *a lot* of processing goes into translating keyboard input into characters. Registering for key events is side-stepping all that processing, and eventually leads to re-implementing it. Which you aren't doing. If a user presses [Shift]+A, for example, the logic you have implemented cannot represent that situation (namely, more than one key being pressed at the same time).

Comment: Faywang-MSFT Two things: 1. the `sawKeyDown` value is not being set to true, which does happen in Debug mode; 2. when I set a breakpoint inside the KeyDown listener Visual Studio shows the message `The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code of the debugger's target code type is associated with this line.` (also listed in my question). In Debug mode I can set a breakpoint inside the handler and it all works as expected.

Comment: Are you compiling the release configuration with debug symbols? Are you setting the [/Zo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zo-enhance-optimized-debugging) compiler option?

Comment: No, `/Zo` is not set, but the project does have the [/Zi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/z7-zi-zi-debug-information-format?view=vs-2019) option set. In Release I can debug the original `KeyUp` handler, but not my `KeyDown` handler. I'm just really confused why my function gets elided when it compiles fine and looks like it should be valid. (the project has `/O2` and `/Oi` flags set)

Comment: If you tried to change the text of tabTextBox in KeyDown event, will the text change?

Comment: Is that lambda trying to modify a local variable on the stack? The method that hooked up the handler will have returned before your lambda gets called, leading to nasty memory corruption.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to capture the local variable in the lambda. I've based the implementation on [this article](https://thispointer.com/c11-lambda-how-to-capture-local-variables-inside-lambda/) I think you're right that the variable will be out of scope by the time I'm expecting the lambda to run - maybe the compiler is smart enough to detect that and omit the handler? Does that mean I need to change the flag to be a member variable? Is there some other place I can keep that variable to access later?

Comment: When I tried this, the sawKeyDown value can be set to true in debug and release mode, the KeyDown event can be triggered successfully, could you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Ryan Shepherd's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63718064/c-winrt-keydown-event-handler-not-being-added-in-release-mode?noredirect=1#comment112862222_63718064) shows what is causing the problem.

The `sawKeyDown` variable was defined locally on the stack, which means it no longer exists when the lambda is invoked (oops!).

The solution was to make the flag a member variable.

```
    // file.h - define the member variable inside the struct/type
    bool _receivedKeyDown{ false };
```

```
    // file.cpp
    tabTextBox.KeyDown([weakThis](const IInspectable&, Input::KeyRoutedEventArgs const&) {
        auto tab{ weakThis.get() };
        tab->sawKeyDown = true;
    });
    
    tabTextBox.KeyUp([weakThis](const IInspectable& sender, Input::KeyRoutedEventArgs const& e) {
        auto tab{ weakThis.get() };
        auto textBox{ sender.try_as<Controls::TextBox>() };
        if (tab && textBox && tab->sawKeyDown)
        {
            // ... original code here...
        }

        tab->sawKeyDown = false;
    });
```